# Replacing an empty entry of a tab-delimited txt

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, notepad++

This is a tab-delimited txt.

```
A    B    D
C
K    s
```

So there is nothing in (2,2), (2,3) (3,3) entry, NOT EVEN TAB.

The maximum length row is 1st row, and 1st row has 3 columns.

Can I simply add 2 tabs to 2nd row, 1 tab to 3rd row, so that this tab-delimited txt becomes a "square"?

**What I have tried**

1. Tried to use notepad++'s replace.

   Find what:(blank), Replace with: \t, Checked 'Match whole word only'.

   It didn't work.

   Find what:(blank), Replace with: \t, Regular expression

   It didn't work.
2. Tried python

   ```
   import fileinput
   for line in fileinput.FileInput("input.txt",inplace=1):
       line = line.replace("",\t)
       print line,
   ```

   It didn't work for this purpose.

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag from your question.  Please avoid using tags that do not adequately describe your problem at hand

Answer (score 3):

In Python you can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for this:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> s = 'A\tB\tD\nC\nK\ts'
>>> data = izip_longest(*(x.split('\t') for x in s.splitlines()), fillvalue='\t')
>>> for line in zip(*data):
      print line
...     
('A', 'B', 'D')
('C', '\t', '\t')
('K', 's', '\t')
```

If you're reading the data from a file:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = izip_longest(*(line.split('\t') for line in f), fillvalue='\t')
    print '\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*data))
```

Comment: That's how I was just writing it!

Comment: @200OK Thank you. What if the input is tab-delimited txt? Replacing by s = 'input.txt'  along doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @user3123767 I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: @200OK I am really sorry, but how can I write the result to output.txt ? And how can I make sure it doesn't show the process in the command window?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'll have to count the TAB occurences in each line and append n TABs.

However, if it's a one time task, MS Excel should help:

1. paste txt file content to worksheet
2. use data -> text to clumn
3. extract the "square" range -> excel should fill up the required TABs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a method to normalise the file content so that it will become a tab-separated value (tsv) file, than you can do something like this:

```
def normalise(lines, max_num_of_columns=None):
    if max_num_of_columns == None:
       max_num_of_columns = max({len(line.split('\t')) for line in lines})
    for line in lines:
        content = line.split('\t')
        while len(content) < max_num_of_columns:
            content.append('')
        print '\t'.join(content)

lines = ['A\tB\tD\nC','K\ts']

normalise(lines)
...
A   B   D
C
K   s
```

If you don't know the max_num_of_columns you have to check the file first (see the first if).

Comment: @nichele The file is not bigger than my RAM. How does I get that max_num_of_columns?

Comment: If you don't know that in advance then you have to search for it. It's a simple search for the maximum:
`max_num_of_columns = max({len(line.split('\t')) for line in lines})`

Comment: I've just updated my solution. Check it out. In the logical steps it's very similar to 200 OK's one. It's just more readable because it's not using the izip_longest function. For this reason I also think his/her solution should scale better.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty ugly and inefficient, but I found this gets the job done:

```
myStr = "A\tB\tD\nC\nK\ts"

maxLen = max([len(line.split('\t')) for line in myStr.split('\n')])

newstr = ''.join([line + ('\t' * (maxLen - len(line.split('\t')))) + '\n' for line in myStr.split('\n')])

>>> newstr
'A\tB\tD\nC\t\t\nK\ts\t\n'
```

might have to be modified a bit depending on how your input looks, how you're handling newlines, etc. But I think that's the basic idea. You find the max length of a line and go through and make all your other lines that length by filling up with tabs.